# URLClassLoader finding X but not Y in same folder

Tags: java, urlclassloader

General idea: I'm writing on a loader for java that allows dynamically reloading classes to allow for changing the implementation, without restarting the entire program to keep the main application running and minimize downtimes. Every external piece of code is grouped by "modules", each module has a main class with a "onEnable, postEnable, onDisable" entry/exit point and can consist of any amount of classes. To load a module, the class containing the entry point is specified, then loaded. I'll reference them as "modules" and "additional classes" in the following, "module" being the class containing the above mentioned functions by implementing the "public interface Module", "additional classes" refer to everything the module would use on runtime but isn't a Module by itself (e.g. we have a Module called "Car implements Module", and that module requires a class "Engine" to function -> "Car" is the module, "Engine" is an additional class")

Code of what I'm doing to load a module initially (name is a String containing the full classname including path, example given later):

```
Class<?> clazz = mainLoader.loadClass(name);
Module module = (Module) clazz.newInstance();
addLoadedModule(module);
enableLoadedModule(module);
```

And here's how I reload the module when it's already existing, so that I can override the implementation. "m" is an instance of the current implementation of the Module that is supposed to be reloaded.

```
boolean differs = false;
Class<?> newClass = null;
try (URLClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(urls, mainLoader.getParent()))
{
    // Try to load the class and check if it differs from the already known one
    newClass = cl.loadClass(m.getClass().getName());
    differs = m.getClass() != newClass;
}
catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e)
{
    // Class couldn't be found, abort.
    e.printStackTrace();
    return;
}
if (!differs)
{
    // New class == old class -> no need to reload it
    return;
}
Module module = null;
try
{
    // Try to instantiate the class
    module = (Module) newClass.newInstance();
}
catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e)
{
    // Can't instantiate, abort
    e.printStackTrace();
    return;
}
// Check versions, only reload if the new implementation's version differs from the current one. Version is a custom annotation, don't worry about that; the version check works fine
Version oldVersion = m.getClass().getAnnotation(Version.class);
Version newVersion = module.getClass().getAnnotation(Version.class);
if (oldVersion.equals(newVersion))
{
    return;
}
// And if everything went well, disable and remove the old module from the list, then add and enable the new module.
disableModule(m);
modules.remove(m);
modules.put(module, false);
enableLoadedModule(module);
```

This is the mainLoader, urls is an URL[] pointing to the location containing the external classes to load:

```
mainLoader = new URLClassLoader(urls, this.getClass().getClassLoader());
```

The problem arises when I try to RE-load an implementation, that requires multiple classes:

Module of class A requires class B to function. This is what happens when I try to dynamically load, then reload class A:

load A -> "Sure, but I'll need B with it." -> automatically loads B -> "Here ya go, A works fine now."
reload A -> "Sure, but I'll need B with it." -> crashes because B couldn't be found

Both classes are located in the exact same folder, structure like this:

- Class A implements Module: com/foo/bar/A.class
- Class B: com/foo/bar/B.class
- urls: ["com/foo/bar/"]

I call the function with load("com.foo.bar.A"), which works when attempting to load it the first time, but fails when trying to reload it as described above.

It works fine when trying to load a "single class module", the problem arises when the module relies on an additional external class. I tried using different classloaders to use as the parent for the URLClassLoader in the reloading process, those being the sysloader, Module.class.getClassLoader(), mainLoader (using that one, it won't ever find the new class definition because it already knows about it and therefor won't even attempt to load it from the drive again) and the mainLoader.getParent(), the classloader of the old module, and the parent of the modules classloader.

I'm probably just overseeing something obvious, but I can't figure out why it would manage to load the "extra" classes the first time, but fail when I reload the base class...

If you need any debug outputs or exact errors let me know, I replaced the debug outputs with comments explaining what does what so I got a fairly detailed log of what's happening when, but I didn't seem it to be necessary as it goes through the entire "check and then load" process just fine, it crashes when trying to enable the module. The "onEnable" method of the module requires the additional class B, that's where it fails. As I said, if you need the implementation of the classes A and B, Module, any other code or the debug outputs let me know and I'll add them in as requested.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few things you can try:

1. Create an extension of UrlClassLoader so that you can track when it loads a class and what class loader is used to load the class.
2. Your other issue is make sure none of these classes are available on the "default" class path as that will cause that version to use. You are not overriding the default  class loading behaviour which is to check the parent for the class first.
3. The other issue you're probably facing relates to the way the VM caches classes - I'm not entirely sure how this works - but from what I've experienced it seems that once a class is loaded it puts it in a shared storage space so that it does not load the class again. This shared space class will not be unloaded until the class loader that loaded it goes unreachable.

Comment: Even though this is not the "answer" to the problem, it contained a hint allowing me to solve the issue: "This shared space class will not be unloaded until the class loader that loaded it goes unreachable." -> As of my code, the classloader is only existant during the try/catch clause where I initially get the class of the new module. As it is closed and removed as soon as I'm done with loading the class, it obviously couldn't load the other classes anymore. I now save the classloader and only close it when a new module is loaded, that way it makes it possible to load the "additional classes"

Answer (score 0):

The solution lies in the classloader being closed and deleted as soon as the loading of the initial class is done, due to the class loader being only existant in the try/catch clause. I solved the issue by storing the classloader in a map until a new implementation of the module is loaded, then I can discard the old loader and store the new one instead.